# Plot point patterns on original images

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

I have a histopatholgy images and I use developed algorithms extracted interested cells as point patters.

Now I want to plot point patterns on the original images, my expectation should be like this:

At first I try to use R to load original image, however, the loaded image are displayed together with axes, and no grid lines as the figure shows. So I was wondering how could I replicate the format as the figure shows exactly.
Thanks!
[image]
Information about the 'fig' variable for plot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggested solution with R, using the `EBImage` package. I like this because of the ease of interacting with the image.

```
# EBImage is required
  if (!require(EBImage)) {
    source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite("EBImage")
    library(EBImage)
  }

# Read the image and plot it with no borders, 300 ppi
  fn <- file.choose() # select saved image
  img <- readImage(fn)
  img <- channel(img, "gray") # gray scale for simplicity
  dev.new(width = dim(img)[1]/300, height = dim(img)[2]/300)
  plot(img)
```

This step takes advantage of the ease of interacting with graphic elements in R. Here, `locator` is used to place a mark at the intersection of grid lines and to record the x, y coordinates. Grid lines are then added to the image under the assumption that the image is oriented with the grid lines running vertically and horizontally.

```
# Use locator() to interactively identify convenient intersections
  pp <- locator(type = "p", pch = 3, col = 2) # end with ctrl-click
```

The following code is not necessary **if** only intersections along the diagonal were chosen. This extra code accomodates an arbitrary number of selections to determine the unique grid lines (as long as choices include one of each grid line). The average value will be determined from multiple choices.

```
# Little more coding to extract and plot unique grid lines
  breaks <- lapply(pp, function(v) hist(v, plot = FALSE)$breaks)
  groups <- Map(cut, pp, breaks)
  pp <- Map(function(v, g) tapply(v, g, mean), pp, groups)
  pp <- lapply(pp, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]) # to re-use if needed

# Place grid lines on new image
  plot(img)
  abline(v = pp$x, h = pp$y, col = 2)
```

Grid lines were added with the simplest base function. More sophisticated lines could be added if desired. To illustrate other possibilities, the coordinates (in pixels) of each grid line is placed here.

```
  text(min(pp$x), pp$y, round(pp$y), col = 2, adj = c(1, -0.2))
  text(pp$x, max(pp$y), round(pp$x), col = 2, adj = c(0, 1.2))
```

And the result of this (having interacted through `locator()`.

[image: Grids added to image with EBImage]

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for your reply! It's really cool, but I was wondering whether I can synergize this plot method with ggplot to make the plot more customizable?

Comment: Hi Haoyang. Thanks for your note! I use both lattice and ggplot but have found that integrating vector graphics and images works best with EBImage and base R. Having learned lots of the details, I also find it easier to control customization with base R. Feel free to describe your needs and I’ll see if I can suggest links or solutions.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your kindness. The reason I like ggplot is that I think it can make plots look beautiful. Here, in my case, I used a package called 'dbscan' and 'largeVis' to visualize large dataset, and the output contains cluster information and distance for visualization, what I want is also plot those visualization on the original image. I edited my question so that you could better understand the visualization result.

Comment: I think I understand a bit more but still have questions. As I understand it, `dbscan` does spatial clustering. The `largeVis` package reduces dimensions from dbscan and can be an alternative to tSNE. It seems that you want to map the *cluster information* and *distances* back onto the **original** 2D image. If this is so, it would be helpful to use `dput()` to provide a subset of the 62665 x 9 data.frame and explain (one more time) just exactly what sort of visualization you want create. That will help others answer your question and increase its value on SO.

Comment: Thank you David, I will look into that!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with OpenCV and Python:

(**EDIT: added vertical lines)**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# draw grid
spacing = 200
color = (255,0,255)  # magenta
linewidth = 5

# horizontal lines
ystart = 20
for i in range(3):
    x1, x2 = 0, img.shape[1]
    y = ystart + spacing * i
    cv2.line(img, (x1,y), (x2,y), color, linewidth)

# vertical lines
xstart = 60
for i in range(3):
    y1, y2 = 0, img.shape[0]
    x = xstart + spacing * i
    cv2.line(img, (x,y1), (x,y2), color, linewidth)


# create a bunch of locations for dots
num = 50
xs = np.random.randint(0,img.shape[1],num)
ys = np.random.randint(0,img.shape[0],num) 

# draw the dots on the image (use red so they stand out)
radius = 10
color = (0,0,255)
for i in range(num):
    cv2.circle(img,(xs[i],ys[i]), radius, color, -1)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image: Image result]

Comment: Thank you for your help! This seems like what I want, and do you know how to add those grid lines?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted *no* gridlines. You can draw any lines you want using  "cv2.line(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), color, linewidth)"

Comment: Yes as you can see, there are some vertical and horizontal lines in the figure, so that the original image looks like a combine of multiple squares.

Comment: Ok, edited the answer to add the grid.  Take another look.